# Animated Loading Gif with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to rotate an image continuously (as in a loading gif) using jQuery? For a static image.  Ideally, could it continually turn at 45 degree angle?

Comment: "Loading" images are usually just a gif animation.

Comment: the devices we are targeting cannot support animated gifs unfortunately

Comment: @Paul Without knowing what the device is, if the device can't handle animated GIFs, are you sure it can handle rotating an image smoothly using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are jQuery libraries that can be used to rotate images, that you can look in to. Have a look at this for instace:

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Found this blog post as well:

http://superdit.com/2011/01/06/rotating-image-using-jquery/

Comment: A good SO answer should be a self contained solution and not rely solely on links to external sources where the reader must then figure out his solution.  And then links go bad.

Comment: Thanks Christofer - you put me on the right lines - the jquery rotate plugin works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single image, then you can do that, but only with a browser that can do rotate transforms. No need to go by steps - smooth all the way around.

```
.rotatable {
    -webkit-animation: Rotate 1s infinite;
}
-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why the OP titled and tagged his question with jQuery... he wants to use more than just CSS confined to webkit.

Comment: Assuming he doesn't know CSS can do it, or that the jQuery just executes the CSS transforms.

Comment: And that it doesn't fully answer his question.